# Set-returning functions are not allowed in UPDATE when using Postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

We have an old Flyway database update

```
UPDATE plays SET album = (regexp_matches(album, '^6,(?:(.+),)?tv\d+'))[1]
```

...that runs fine with any Postgres version from 9.2 to 9.6 but fails with latest Postgres 10. Happens even when ran directly without any JDBC.

```
ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in UPDATE
```

Is there a backwards incompatibility I didn't notice from version 10 release notes? Is there a workaround?

Comment: you can use `regexp_match()` instead

Comment: And yes there was a change in behaviour. See the item "*Change the implementation of set-returning functions appearing in a query's SELECT list (Andres Freund)*" in the release notes: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-10.html  (5th bullet point in the section "Migration to Version 10")

Comment: *I* would use `substring (album FROM '^6,(?:(.+),)?tv\d+')`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I needed the solution to keep compatibility with older Postgres versions so if you write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is untested, but should work in all PostgreSQL versions:

```
UPDATE plays SET album = substring (album FROM '^6,(?:(.+),)?tv\d+');
```

Answer (score 10):

I had a more general problem where I needed the second match from a regex.

The solution was a nested subselect

```
SET my_column = (SELECT a.matches[2] from 
    (SELECT regexp_matches(my_column, '^(junk)?(what_i_want)$') matches) a)
```

Or modify the regex to return one group and apply @LaurenzAlbe 's answer:

```
SET my_column = substring (my_column FROM '^junk?(what_i_want)$')
```

There may be cases where modifying the regex is not ideal.

The original was of the form

```
SET my_column = regexp_matches(my_column, '^(junk)?(what_i_want)$')[2]
```

Where `junk` and `what_i_want` were fairly complex rexex fragments.